# WPF Framework Classes/Project => UNO? Is that possible?

Tags: uno-platform

In the last years i have developed a huge amount of .NET Framework (4.8) Classes with functions and methods for my applications. Most if this apps are commandline apps. A few apps are WPF or Winform-Apps.

Now I want to start with Apps they run in browser. I try to use "Blazor", but the need .NET CORE or .NET STANDARD - and they cann´t use projects/classes from ".NET Framework".

My Question: If i use uno-platform only for UI, can I use/reference to ".NET Framework" Projects oder Libraries? Or have it the same limitation like Razor-Apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uno Platform in the browser and Blazor share the same underlying .NET WebAssembly runtime, so they have the same limitations in this regard. If you want to use older code you'll need to recompile it, and you won't have access to .NET Framework-only APIs.

Answer (score 0):

FYI Michael. This WPF -> Uno Platform migration topic will be covered at UnoConf 2021 session (Nov 30). [www.unoconf.com](http://www.unoconf.com)